# Travel to Saudi Arabia

Tags: iran, saudi-arabia, war-zones

I am currently booked to travel to *Dammam* in Saudi Arabia, next door to the Persian Gulf and across the water from Iran, this Friday. I am greatly concerned by the developments in Iran and Iraq over the previous few days and the increased tension in the region.

Is there anybody currently in the Eastern region of Saudi Arabia who can give some personal insight into the current situation in Saudi Arabia? I would like to hear from someone on the ground about whether there has been any indication of danger, threats, or higher tension in the region...will it be safe to travel at this time or is it better to cancel my trip?

Comment: I think you should check your country foreign office. Local people see thing differently: in case of war, the foreign could be attacked, usually not the locals.

Comment: I'd also add that this current situation is changing at least day to day.  So past performance may not be a predictor of future actions.

Comment: Very good - I have contacted my foreign office (I should say I am white and live in a Western Country) and as of yet there is no advice against travelling to SA (only against Iran / Iraq). My partner who is white female will also be travelling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am Saudi Arabian, being close to to the Arabian Gulf does not mean anything. The act is between Iran and the US, and the act seems to be done.

There is nothing to worry about. Most likely Saudi is safer than wherever you are coming from.

Answer (score 3):

The current conflict is between US and Iran, and is occurring largely on Iraqi territory.  Unless it escalates into full-blown war, which both sides appear to be very keen to avoid, it is **exceedingly unlikely** that this would have any impact on Saudi Arabia.

Comment: Please could you share the evidence with which you speak? Are you currently in the region?

Comment: @lux Not there now, but I've spent plenty of time in Saudi, and  it's simple geopolitics. Saudi Arabia is not directly involved in this -- it's like avoiding traveling to Canada because there was a drug gang shooting in Mexico.